# I can not download and show place's website, phone number and price level (google places, swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3, google-places-api

I created this class

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation


private let geometryKey = "geometry"
private let locationKey = "location"
private let latitudeKey = "lat"
private let longitudeKey = "lng"
private let nameKey = "name"
private let openingHoursKey = "opening_hours"
private let openNowKey = "open_now"
private let vicinityKey = "vicinity"
private let typesKey = "types"
private let photosKey = "photos"
private let phoneNumberKey = "phoneNumber"
private let ratingKey = "rating"
private let priceLevelKey = "priceLevel"
private let websiteKey = "website"


class QPlace: NSObject  {

    var location: CLLocationCoordinate2D?
    var name: String?
    var photos: [QPhoto]?
    var vicinity: String?
    var isOpen: Bool?
    var types: [String]?
    var rating: Float?
    var priceLevel: Int?
    var website: String?
    var phoneNumber: String?

    init(placeInfo:[String: Any]) {
        // coordinates
        if let g = placeInfo[geometryKey] as? [String:Any] {
            if let l = g[locationKey] as? [String:Double] {
                if let lat = l[latitudeKey], let lng = l[longitudeKey] {
                    location = CLLocationCoordinate2D.init(latitude: lat, longitude: lng)
                }
            }
        }


        // name
        name = placeInfo[nameKey] as? String

        // opening hours
        if let oh = placeInfo[openingHoursKey] as? [String:Any] {
            if let on = oh[openNowKey] as? Bool {
                isOpen = on
            }
        }

        // vicinity
        vicinity = placeInfo[vicinityKey] as? String

        // types
        types = placeInfo[typesKey] as? [String]

        // rating
        rating = placeInfo[ratingKey] as? Float

        //priceLevel
        priceLevel = placeInfo[priceLevelKey] as? Int

        //website
        website = placeInfo[websiteKey] as? String

        //phoneNumber
        phoneNumber = placeInfo[phoneNumberKey] as? String

        // photos
        photos = [QPhoto]()
        if let ps = placeInfo[photosKey] as? [[String:Any]] {
            for p in ps {
                photos?.append(QPhoto.init(photoInfo: p))
            }
        }
    }

    func getDescription() -> String {

        var s : [String] = []

        if let types = types {
            s.append("\(types.joined(separator: ", "))")
        }

        if let rating = rating {
            s.append("Rating: \(rating)")
        }

        if let priceLevel = priceLevel {
            s.append("Price level: \(priceLevel)")
        }

        if let isOpen = isOpen {
            s.append(isOpen ? "OPEN NOW" : "CLOSED NOW")
        }

        if let phoneNumber = phoneNumber {
            s.append("Phone number:\(phoneNumber)")
        }

        if let website = website {
            s.append("\(website)")
        }


        if let vicinity = vicinity {
            s.append("\(vicinity)")
        }
        return s.joined(separator: "\n")
    }


     func getDescriptionMaps() -> String {

        var m : [String] = []

        if let vicinity = vicinity {
            m.append("\(vicinity)")
        }



        return m.joined(separator: "\n")
    }





    func heightForComment(_ font: UIFont, width: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
        let desc = getDescription()
        let rect = NSString(string: desc).boundingRect(with: CGSize(width: width, height: CGFloat(MAXFLOAT)), options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: font], context: nil)
        return ceil(rect.height)
    }


}
```

to show in the cells of a tableView the places details (i'm working with google places). My problem is that website, price level and phone number do not work (it doesn't download and show in the tableView), initially i thought some places might not have data for these information, but trying to look for lots of places and adding some break points i noticed that maybe the problem is the format i used to website, price level and phone number. This is the doc for google places details https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/reference/interface_g_m_s_place.html#a08b7eb6929bc733c0e36cf36d82fa34b
Someone can help me to solve this problem?

Comment: `website` should be of `Url` type and `priceLevel` should be of enum `GMSPlacesPriceLevel` type

Comment: so how can i change in url type? is the first time i trying to do something like that

Comment: declear website as `var website: Url?` and parse as `website = placeInfo[websiteKey] as? Url`

Comment: is not working the same